# How to access key from [Any] using swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, nsmutablearray, any

Am developing a application using swift,in my am integrating cometchat following the link  https://docs.cometchat.com/ios-sdk/quick-start/. So am fetching chat history from the server.

Now I got two(sender messages and receiver messages) nsmutablearray value from the server.

i.e.,  `var firstArr = response!["history"]! as! NSMutableArray`

```
   var secondArr = response!["history"]! as! NSMutableArray
```

I merged two nsmuatblearray values and the result i got is:

```
 [
    {
        from = 1;
        id = 68;
        localmessageid = "46A9A5E5-FEEC-4588-B7D6-18E88BA68393_2";
        message = "ckeck messages";
       "message_type" = 10;
        old = 1;
        self = 1;
        sent = 1521185409000;
    }, 
    {
        from = 2;
        id = 69;
        localmessageid = "46A9A5E5-FEEC-4588-B7D6-18E88BA68393_1";
        message = "sent to thiyakarajan";
       "message_type" = 10;
        old = 1;
        self = 1;
        sent = 1521185410000;
    }
 ]
```

In the responses key value sent is refered as timestamp.

using that sent key(timestamp) help me to sort array in ascending 
   order.

And also me to load message value in table view.

Thanks

Comment: you have to convert that response in using json serialization into Dictionary then you can access to all your object properties

Comment: self.instanceOfCometChat.getHistory("1", messageId: "0", success: { (response) in
                    
              self.firstArr = response!["history"]! as! NSMutableArray
                   
                    
                }, failure: { (error) in
                    
                     print("get error:\(error.debugDescription)")
                    
                })

Comment: This is how am getting my response from server.How can use here a  json serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Array in `cellforrowatindexpath` method of your TableView by using code like `[[yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"message"]`. By using this line you can access the value of message of the array at indexPath 0. Also for sorting the Array depending on timestamp please refer the below code:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"sent" ascending: YES];
return [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

We have used the same in our ReadyUI code. Please refer our ReadyUI source code and email us at support@cometchat.com if you need additional assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad practice working with network data like that. Especially if you want to use this data further inside of your app.

1. You need to parse the data received either in `Dictionary` or in your own data structure to work with it safely. There're plenty of ways to do that including `JSONSerialization`, `Codable Protocol` or even external libraries like `SwiftyJSON`
2. After parsing you will have your objects that you can work with without necessity of casting `Any` type to expected types, which brings a lot of optional checks. So let's say you have your structure called `Message` that contains all the data from JSON, after getting all the objects you'll have your neat `[Message]` array that you can pass around the application.
3. To sort array by some of the properties you simply use function `sorted(by:)` that is default for any collection. In your case: `sortedArray = myArray.sorted(by: {$0.sent < $1.sent})`
4. Now you can use this array as a dataSource for your tableView using `UITableViewDataSource` protocol

It's obvious that you're pretty new to iOS programming, so I'd recommend to look up for some tutorials on working with networking data. You can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_c0pAz3UPEs) for example, it pretty much sums up everything mentioned above.

Comment: self.CometChat.getHistory("1", messageId: "0", success: { (response) in self.firstArr = response!["history"]! as! NSMutableArray }, failure: { (error) in print("get error:(error.debugDescription)") })

Comment: This is how am getting my response from server.How can use here a json serialization

Comment: Okay, you're already having an Array of Dictionaries here so you won't need it. I'd recommend having your data structure and just map dict data into that object.

Comment: when i merged two nsmutablearray i.e..let mergeArray = self.firstArr.addingObjects(from: self.secondArr as [AnyObject]).This gives array in [Any].I have to access the key.How to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Do code like this

```
Save Swift Array
var firstArr : Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = response!["history"]! as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>

Access valus
let strMessage : String  = fistArr[index]["message"] as! String
```

Will works..!

Comment: yes it works...i have two array like above you entered that is var firstArr and var secondArr..Now i have merged both array by let mergedArray = self.firstArr.addingObjects(from: self.secondArr as [AnyObject])..Now i returned values in [Any], now i cant access that array